# CSS / HTML Navigation and Logo on same line

Tags: html, css, navigation

I can't figure out how to put them on the same line.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dovZdQ

```
<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <div id="navigation-container">
            <img src="logo.png"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you post your css?

Comment: Its my first time posting code here and It gives me some kind of error when I try to post the CSS. Thats why I added a codepen link, can't u go there ?

Comment: Try adding `float:left;` to your `img`.

Comment: @ДениславАнгелов yes, but the link might break somewhere in the future, so it is best practice to place the relevant coding in your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `<ul>` is by default a block element, make it `inline-block` instead:

```
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

### [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJWOBV)

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question. How can I center the nav on the bar now ?

Comment: @ДениславАнгелов `text-align:center;` on `.navigation-bar`. Or a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJWOBV

Comment: Maybe I didn't asked correctly. I want to center only the nav menu, without the logo.

Comment: @ДениславАнгелов for that, it is easiest to float the image : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJWOBV

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, let's use some semantic HTML.

```
<nav class="navigation-bar">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In fact, you can even get away with the more minimalist:

```
<nav class="navigation-bar">
    <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Projects</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Get in Touch</a>
</nav>
```

Then add some CSS:

```
.navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;  /* i'm assuming full width */
    height: 80px; /* change it to desired width */
    background-color: red; /* change to desired color */
}
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;    /* if you want it vertically middle of the navbar. */
}
.navigation-bar > a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 80px;        /* if you want it to take the full height of the bar */
    line-height: 80px;    /* if you want it vertically middle of the navbar */
}
```

Obviously, the actual margins, heights and line-heights etc. depend on your design.

Other options are to use tables or floats for layout, but these are generally frowned upon.

Last but not least, I hope you get cured of div-itis.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the `logo` class to the image...then float the `ul`

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mJWqjZ)

**HTML**

```
<img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/hCrQkJi.png">
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll advise you use CSS Flex.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation-container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #352d2f;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
 <head>
        <link href="./answer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="navigation-bar">
      
      
          <div id="navigation-container">
      
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hCrQkJi.png">
      
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  background-color: #352d2f;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation-container img {
  float: left;
}

#navigation-container ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
}

#navigation-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

#navigation-container li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#menu {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

1) you can float the image to the left:

```
<img style="float:left" src="http://i.imgur.com/hCrQkJi.png">
```

2)You can use an HTML table to place elements on one line.

Code below

```
  <div class="navigation-bar">
    <div id="navigation-container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hCrQkJi.png"></td>
          <td><ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Get in Touch</a></li>
        </ul>
          </td></tr></table>
    </div>
```

Comment: tables should never be used for layouts!